# Scala: Get Items from Seq by given index (all the items above given index)

Tags: scala, seq

I am new to scala, the way I understood Seq is that its an ordered list. So I was wanted to see if I can get all the items based on a given index where retrieved items index is lesser than the given items index.

Lets say I have Seq:

```
scala> val s = Seq(1, 2, 34 ,44 )
s: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 34, 44)
```

Given index index as 3rd item I was expecting to get all the items(values) that has a lower index position than the given index.

Keep this in mind I wrote the following and Looks like I am wrong.

```
scala> val x = s.map {
     | id => id < s.indexOf(3) }
x: Seq[Boolean] = List(false, false, false, false)
```

What what I want is Seq(1,2,34) as the output because if of those element's index is less than the index of 44.

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: `s.take(2) = List(1, 2)`. What do you want the output to be?

Comment: @Brian just updated the question

Comment: See the answer from @0__.

Comment: Keep in mind that depending on how you're producing that index, there might be a better way to do the broader thing you're aiming for. I generally consider index munging to be a bit of a code smell except in most contexts. For example, if the index came from a call to find the index of something, then use `takeWhile`. (Just trying to guard against http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s.take(3)` will take the first three elements of the sequence, i.e. all elements whose index is smaller than 3 (index counts from zero).